# How would one fake kerning adjustments in propertized text?

Tags: text-properties, display

I've successfully managed adjusting the displayed size of spaces and raising/lowering propertized text by making use of the `display` property, however I cannot find anything that would allow me to fake kerning adjustments.  In other words, I have two letters and would like to make the second one intrude into the first one's bounding box, in typography this would be done with negative kerning.  Is there a way to achieve this effect with the Emacs display engine?

edit: I'll give a demonstration of what I want to achieve:

```
(defun my-insert-tex ()
  (insert
   (propertize (concat "T" (propertize "e" 'display '(raise -0.24)) "X")
               'font-lock-face '(:family "Serif"))))
```

The preceding function inserts the string "TeX" with the "e" lowered by 0.5ex which are roughly 24% of the font height.  This approximates the typesetting of the [TeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) logo, however to make it perfect I'd need something like a negative margin around the "e" to move it closer to the "T".

Comment: Have you asked on the mailing list? I have a feeling this is just not supported.

Comment: No I haven't, I hoped it to be something simple I've just happened to overlook.